# Assembly containing type XXXX.XXXX.XXX.XXXX is not referenced when running a C# based service in AX 2012 batch job?

Tags: x++, dynamics-ax-2012, ax, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

I have created a project using Visual studio to consume web service, and when running on a AX-client it works perfectly.

But when running same using batch job it gives error like:
Assembly containing type XXXX.XXXX.XXX.XXXX is not referenced.
Object 'CLRObject' could not be created.

Does anyone have a solution for this???

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to install the assembly which contains your type into the GAC of the batch AOS. Perhaps you also have to restart the AOS after installing the assembly to flush some caches.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for replying, but AOS is already restarted with no result. @DAXaholic